# SSH X11 forwarding works only for WSL but not to a remote Host

Tags: ssh, windows-11, x11-forwarding, ubuntu-22.04, vcxsrv

I have a remote PC running Ubuntu 22.04. From another PC running Windows 11 I can connect via OpenSSH to the remote Host. However I am not able to use X11 forwarding (with the -X option) to launch a GUI application such as xclock.

Currently I have the following workarounds:

- Launch WSL and connect from the WSL to the remote PC
- install and launch an X11 server (VcXsrv), define "10" as the new display, disable access control and connect via ssh. On the remote side export DISPLAY=[IP]:10.0 with IP being the IP-Address of the Windows PC.

In both cases I am connecting via

```
ssh -X user@host
```

It seems that Windows 11 already has a built-in X11 Server that only works for WSL by default..

Is there simpler way that does not require me to manually define IP Adresses or use the WSL as an intermediate?

Comment: You say "I am not able to use X11 forwarding..." Please [edit] your question to describe exactly what happens when you try. Do you get any error messages? What do they say?